# What's the highest altitude ever achieved by a (rocket-?)plane for level flight?

Tags: aviation-history, high-altitude, rocket

As probably most of us know, the SR-71 Blackbird holds the altitude record for leveled flight for (manned) jet planes (and ground-launched planes) at 90,000 ft MSL. However, the very altitude record in leveled flight is probably held by a rocketplane, such as the Bell X-1 or the North American X-15. Is there an altitude record for *leveled* flight that surpassed that of the Blackbird? What's the record for the highest horizontal flight by a rocket (or any other type of) plane? May include unmanned ones.

Edit: To make it clear, my question asks for the altitude record of a winged *air*craft that could sustain this altitude aerodynamically. But Abdullah answered my question anyway, it was the NASA Helios propeller craft (which looks a bit weird but still is a winged aircraft) that reached and sustained an altitude of 96900 ft (29,500 m). Wikipedia says this is the altitude record for aerodynamic horizontal flight.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Could you clarify what exactly you would count as a rocket-plane? Would the space shuttle count?

Comment: @Bianfable Thank you. No, because the Space Shuttle didn't fly aerodynamically leveled with engine on. The point is that the rocket-engine is on while flying. So no gliding unless the altitude can be maintained regardless (like by a sailplane).

Comment: @Abdullah Thank you. That's actually an answer rather than a comment since the link states it's the highest winged craft in leveled flight ever. Why would it be difficult for rocketplanes to fly horizontally?

Comment: @Giovanni: "Why would it be difficult for rocketplanes to fly horizontally?" – It's not difficult, it just doesn't make sense. If you're aerodynamically flying horizontally, then you don't need a rocket. If you need a rocket that means you expect to be flying where there's no oxygen, but then you are going up not level, and you're not flying aerodynamically.

Comment: @JörgWMittag But if a pilot wanted to fly horizontally at too high altitude for whatever reason, they'd need a rocketplane because jet planes can't fly there due to the lack of oxygen as you point out, and propeller planes don't get fast enough to get too high because they shouldn't break the sound barrier.

Comment: @Giovanni if one is really going to go that high, then it would be better to just design a jet engine that can breathe up there. It's not physically impossible or impractical anyway.

Comment: @Giovanni --it's not clear what exactly would disqualify the Space Shuttle *in orbit* from the question.  I think you need to specify *non-oribital* horizontal flight.

Comment: @quietflyer In orbit it doesn't fly but float through (near-)vacuum in free fall, and its nose doesn't need to have horizontal pitch. Also, this is aviation SE, not space SE. But feel free to understand this question as "other than the Space Shuttle and the Buran". (:

Comment: @Giovanni, would a sub-orbital ICBM meet your definition of horizontal flight in an unmanned rocket?  If not, why not?

Comment: @MichaelHall the trajectory would only be horizontal instantaneously, at the exact peak of the arc, right?

Comment: @Giovanni -- wouldn't "sustained horizontal flight" or something to that effect be clearer than "levelled"?  I'm assuming it's the flight path not the pitch attitude that you actually want to specify.  (Or maybe both?)  Plus the issue of whether *instantaneously* level is sufficient--?  At present the question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: @quiet flyer, yes, but duration at "level" wasn't specified, plus an ICBM flies a rather shallow trajectory at roughly 5:1 horizontal to vertical.  And at scales where "level" is not the same as "straight":  i.e. Curvature of the earth is a factor.  (even more so than in other questions insinuating that in a small plane downforce is needed to follow the earth and avoid flying into space...)

Comment: "even more so than in other questions insinuating that in a small plane downforce is needed to follow the earth and avoid flying into space"-- that such a thing is not needed, is proof that the earth isn't round --  :)

Comment: agreed with quiet flyer about "sustained horizontal flight" which could relate to "ceiling"

Comment: @MichaelHall An ICBM doesn't qualify because it's not a plane (not a winged aircraft). It's not even an aircraft at all but a spacecraft actually. My question is concerning aerodynamic sustaining of altitude.

Comment: You should go ahead and make an answer out of the Helios and accept it. Not sure why the comment was deleted.